# Android - best way to verify internet connection when internet led from modem is red?

Tags: android, networking

I know this have been asked a lot of times, but none of this answer resolve my problem, my question is when my modem is restarting starts to turn on leds such as power(obviously), dns, wireless, DSL and internet, when internet led is in yellow colour means that there is internet but when is in red colour all the codes I have(see below) return to true when is obviously that there is no internet(you can't navigate this way)[image]

here is the codes of methods (isConnectingToInternet,isOnline,haveNetworkConnection) I have (and all returning true when internet led is red)

```
public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null)
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null)
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
          return false;
    }



public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


public boolean haveNetworkConnection() {
        boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;
        }
        return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
    }
```

How can I verify when led is red? any method? thanks

Comment: It would help to know what the red LED signifies in terms of the router's operations. Do you have the manual?

Answer (score 2):

I answered that within [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141129/android-how-to-check-if-google-is-available/21469343#21469343), but it might be an answer to this one too. My solution, basically, is based on setting a `Socket` to Google on the `80` port.

I use the following code on many of my projects:

```
Socket socket;
final String host = "www.google.com";
final int port = 80;
final int timeout = 30000;   // 30 seconds of timeout

try {
  socket = new Socket();
  socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), timeout);
}
catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
  Log.e("GoogleSock", "I couldn't resolve the host you've provided!");
}
catch (SocketTimeoutException ste) {
  Log.e("GoogleSock", "After a reasonable amount of time, I'm not able to connect, Google is probably down!");
}
catch (IOException ioe) {
  Log.e("GoogleSock", "Hmmm... Sudden disconnection, probably you should retry once again!");
}
```

If response time is important to you, this might be tricky, though. Precisely on `UnknownHostException`s, it may take longer to timeout, about 45 seconds. If you have a connection issue, this shouldn't be fired though. Actually, any of the exceptions being thrown would mean you probably at 99.999% have a connection issue.

Anyway, if response time is important to you and you want to hedge your bets, you could solve this by two ways:

- Don't use a host, use an IP address instead. You may get several Google's IPs just using `ping` several times on the host. For instance:

  ```
  shut-up@i-kill-you ~/services $ ping www.google.com
  PING www.google.com (173.194.40.179) 56(84) bytes of data.
  ```
- Another workaround would be starting a `WatchDog` thread and finish the connection attempt after the required time. Evidently, forcely finishing would mean no success, so in your case, Google would be down.